# How can we factor out the maximum value of f'(x) in an integral with an absolute value?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, inequality

I'm currently trying to understand a proof concerning the error term in the left- and right Riemann sums to approximate a definite integral. What I can't seem to understand is the last three lines of the proof where the author first factors out the maximum value of the derivative of f and sets up an inequality? The second part of my question then is how the author expands the integral to get the squared bracketed terms and the term 1/2.

[Proof Image from Research Paper]https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywGd9.jpg

Comment: That image may disappear with time. Please type it out here, or at a minimum, upload the image here.

Answer (score 0):

1. The mean value theorem.
2. Splitting up the integral into $\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x^*_k} + \int_{x^*_k}^{x_k}$, doing it, and then using the fact that $x_k^*$ is between $x_{k-1}$ and $x_k$ so $(x_k-x^*_k)^2 \le (x_k-x_{k-1})^2$ and similarly for $(x_{k-1}-x^*_k)^2$

Answer (score 0):

By the Mean Value Theorem you have
$$
f(x)-f(x_k^*)=f'(\xi)(x-x_k^*)\leq(x-x_k^*)\max_{[a,b]}{f'}.
$$
Then, by integrating $x-x_k^*$ you get
$$
\frac{1}{2}(x-x_k^*)^2
$$
but you should be careful with the absolute value and separate the part in which $x\geq x_k^*$ and the other one where $x<x_k^*.$